# Can't connect to VNC even though port is open and service is visible

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, vnc, buffalo-router

A client with a small office network (under 20 devices) had me replace a malfunctioning Netgear router with a Buffalo WHR-600D router. On the previous router, I had set up port forwarding with custom ports for VNC so I could log in and provide tech support remotely to a handful of machines. After installing the new router, I configured its DHCP settings to assign static IP addresses to those same machines, and set up port forwarding using the same ports.

Unfortunately, I'm not able to connect VNC over the Internet, although I can connect to them via the LAN. Here's the thing — I can see that the ports are forwarded correctly. When I go to canyouseeme.org, I get 'success' on each of the ports I've configured! I've confirmed that each port is forwarding TCP and UDP to the correct address. I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Please post results of a remote `telnet externalip 5900` (assuming 5900TCP is your VNC port) to check if RFB header is remotely received.

Comment: "I'm not able to connect VNC over the Internet" is not very detailed info about the exact error message you get nor the VNC client you are using.